# Find multiple strings, copy entire row and paste into another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to find certain names on a worksheet, copy the entire row once it finds said name and paste it on another worksheet.

I wrote code that finds one of the names, then copies the row and pastes it to another sheet.

```vb
Sub Macro2()

Dim StatusCol As Range
Dim Status As Range
Dim PasteCell As Range

Set StatusCol = Sheet10.Range("A1:AV1569")

For Each Status In StatusCol
    If Sheet11.Range("A2") = "" Then
        Set PasteCell = Sheet11.Range("A2")
    Else
        Set PasteCell = Sheet11.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    End If
    
    If Status = "Jane Thompson" Then Status.Offset(0, -4).Resize(1, 5).Copy PasteCell
    
Next Status
        
End Sub
```

Instead of finding only one string, the "Jane Thompson" name, I want to loop through a list of names, find each, copy the entire row where they are located and paste the row into another sheet. I have all the names on another worksheet (about 80 different names)

I managed to find code that gives me the desired output:

```vb
Sub FruitBasket()

Dim rngCell As Range
Dim lngLstRow As Long
Dim strFruit() As String
Dim intFruitMax As Integer

intFruitMax = 3
ReDim strFruit(1 To intFruitMax)

strFruit(1) = "Fruit 2"
strFruit(2) = "Fruit 5"
strFruit(3) = "Fruit 18"

lngLstRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For Each rngCell In Range("A2:A" & lngLstRow)
    For i = 1 To intFruitMax
        If strFruit(i) = rngCell.Value Then
            rngCell.EntireRow.Copy
            Sheets("Inventory").Select
            Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Sheets("Fruit").Select
        End If
    Next i
Next

End Sub
```

But instead of 3 items in the array, I had to hard code 81 names. Is there any way to pull the items of an array from another sheet?

Comment: Several ways. Where do you have defined your names? Are they stored in a sheet? You don't want to hardcode 80 names in your code.

Comment: @FunThomas     Yup, they are stored in a sheet, say sheet 12. They are all stored in a column, from A1 to A83. I was thinking in doing it with some sort of double loop or nested loop but i am unsure how to actually write the code to do it properly.

Comment: Congratulations on making your first post to StackOverflow! In your case, it would probably be useful to provide an example of the input sheet and the expected result(s).

Comment: @Fredrik Thank you! I have managed to find a code that produces the desired output, but i had to hardcode 80 names in an array for that and then use a loop (i have edited the main post showing the code). Do you know if there is any way to pull those names from a list in a sheet into an array, so i don't have to hardcode them? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the sheet name and range of the names list ?

Comment: @CDP1802 The sheet name where the list of names is located is named as "Names" and the range is from A1 to A81 (A1:A81). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

With the names in an array you can use [Match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match) rather than looping through them.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FruitBasket()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsInv As Worksheet
    Dim rngCell As Range, v As Variant, arNames
    Dim lngLastRow As Long, lngInvRow As Long
 
    With Sheets("Names")
        lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        arNames = .Range("A2:A" & lngLastRow)
    End With
     
    Set wsInv = Sheets("Inventory")
    With wsInv
        lngInvRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
     
        For Each rngCell In .Range("A2:A" & lngLastRow)
            ' check if value is in array
            v = Application.Match(rngCell, arNames, 0)
            If IsError(v) Then
                ' no match
            Else
                ' match
                rngCell.EntireRow.Copy
                lngInvRow = lngInvRow + 1
                wsInv.Cells(lngInvRow, "A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
        Next
        
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Done"
    
End Sub
```